# can i connect my the Android Emulator (AVD) to a real access point?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to the android development and i am using android studio.
i have tried to connect to my WIFI with Android emulatori but i am not able.
I just want to know if i can connect the Android Emulator to a real wifi instead of AndroidWifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator does not provide virtual hardware for Wi-Fi if you use API 24 or earlier but if you use API 25 or newer it should connect only on AndroWifi